# Multiple definitions of init_module and cleanup_module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to compile multiple source files into a single module. I am having issues with multiple definition of functions.

Here is the code snippet of file1.c file

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "headerfile.h"

#include <linux/slab.h>


static void swarm_init(void) 
{

printk(KERN_ALERT "swarm_init function called\n"); 

}


void* func1(void) {
.....some code here

}

static void swarm_exit(void) 
{

printk(KERN_ALERT "swarm_exit: exit function called"); 

}

module_init(swarm_init);
module_exit(swarm_exit);
```

Second file is as follows

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "headerfile.h"

#include <linux/slab.h>


static void test_init(void)
{

printk(KERN_ALERT "Test init\n");
 void *x;
 x = func1();

}

static void test_exit(void) 
{

printk(KERN_ALERT "test: exit function called"); 

}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);
```

headerfile.h is as follows

```
#ifndef _HEADERFILE_H
#define _HEADERFILE_H


 typedef struct _hashmap_element{
int key;
int in_use;
void* data;
} hashmap_element;

typedef struct _hashmap_map{
int table_size;
int size;
hashmap_element *data;
} hashmap_map;

void *func1(void);

#endif
```

And my makefile is

```
obj-m :=myfile.o
myfile-objs := file1.o file2.o 

all: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I keep getting multiple definition of init_module and cleanup_module.

any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Single module may have at most one initialization (declared with `module_init()` macro) and one cleanup (`module_exit()`) function. If you need initialization  functionality for several parts of your module, you need to combine them manually into single initialization function. The same is true for cleanup.